# MYSQL Selecting data from two different tables and no common variable name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables : Employee and Customer. Customer has customer ID, name, cust state, cust rep# and employee has employee first name, last name, employee phone number, employee number. **Employee number = Cust Rep#.**

I'm trying to extract employee first name, last name and employee phone number who serve customers that live in CA. This is what I had as a code but i get an error saying it returns more than one row

```
SELECT EMP_LNAME,
       EMP_FNAME,
       EMP_PHONE 
FROM employee 
WHERE EMP_NBR =
              (SELECT CUST_REP
               FROM customer 
               WHERE CUST_STATE='CA') ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that your inner query returns multiple rows, so change it to `where EMP_NBR in` to retrieve all matches.

The problem your query has is that it doesn't make sense to say `= (a set which returns multiple rows)`, since it's unclear what exactly should be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN()` instead of `=` when expecting a set of results to be returned in the subquery (rather than a single scalar result):

```
select EMP_LNAME,EMP_FNAME,EMP_PHONE 
from employee 
where EMP_NBR IN (
  select CUST_REP from customer where CUST_STATE='CA'
);
```

Alternatively, you can use an INNER JOIN (or CROSS JOIN with a WHERE filter) to possibly do this more efficiently:

```
SELECT EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_PHONE
FROM employee
INNER JOIN customer ON employee.EMP_NBR = customer.CUST_REP
WHERE customer.CUST_STATE = 'CA';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested query - better to write your query like this

```
select employee.emp_lname, employee.emp_fname, employee.emp_phone
from employee inner join customer
on employee.emp_nbr= customer.cust_rep
where customer.cust_state = 'CA'
```

You are getting that error message because there are several customers in California. This will not be a problem with the above query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMP_LNAME,
       EMP_FNAME,
       EMP_PHONE 
FROM employee 
WHERE EMP_NBR IN
                (SELECT CUST_REP 
                 FROM customer 
                 WHERE CUST_STATE='CA') ;
```